# Tight binding operators in 2D lattice system

Tags: condensed-matter, lattice-model, tight-binding

I have a very naive problem about lattice system, how to translate common operators defined in the bulk ($\hat{x}$, $\hat{p}$...) into their lattice analogues.

In a single- band tight-binding description, the hopping Hamiltonian is taken in the form

$$\hat{H}_0=-J(\sum_{m,n} a^{\dagger}_{m+1,n}a_{m,n}+a^{\dagger}_{m,n+1}a_{m,n}+H.c)$$

Then in the limit of lattice constant $a\rightarrow0$, how can we recover the usual kinetic energy term?

$$\hat{H}_0=\frac{1}{2m^*}(\hat{p}_x^2+\hat{p_y}^2),$$ with a effective mass $m^*=1/(2Ja^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to realise here, is that in your Hamiltonian formulation, the lattice constant is implicitly stated as being $b=1$ (I'm calling it b, not to confuse it with the lattice operators). Next you can identify, if you're working in two dimensions, $x=am$ and $y=bn$ yielding

$$\hat{H}_0=-J(\sum_{(x/b),(y/b)} a^{\dagger}_{x+b,y}a_{x,y}+a^{\dagger}_{x,y+b}a_{x,y}+H.c)$$

Now you can take both factors $a^{-1}$ in the summation in front, giving an overall factor of $1/Jb^2$

$->$ $$\hat{H}_0=-\frac{J}{b^2}(\sum_{x,y} a^{\dagger}_{x+b,y}a_{x,y}+a^{\dagger}_{x,y+b}a_{x,y}+H.c)$$

Going on we want to find the momenta I guess. I couldn't write this out fast, I wish I had more time, since it's a good exercise.
But I think the key point is that you see that the momentum $p_x$ is something like $i\hbar\partial_x$. (We set $\hbar$ to $1$, and the $i$ turns out to get squared anyway if I look at what should come out, thus taking care of the minus sign in your original hamiltonian.)

Acting with $\partial_x$ on for instance $a$ yields:
$$ \partial_x a_{x,y} = \frac{a_{x+b,y}-a_{x,y}}{b} $$

Somewhere along these lines the solution should pop up, I think. It's a matter of finding the right re-ordering of the terms in your hamiltonian and seeing that some products can be written in a different way. Maybe if I've got time tonight I'll look at it again.
Best of luck!
L